# Decimal chapter numbering in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

I am trying to number my chapters in Libreoffice decimally. The best way to illustrate what I mean is by an example:

```
1 Chapter One
1.1 Chapter One Sub One
1.2 Chapter One Sub Two
1.2.1 Chapter One Sub Two Sub One
1.2.2 Chapter One Sub Two Sub Two
1.3 Chapter One Sub Three
2 Chapter Two
2.1 Chapter Two Sub One
2.2 Chapter Two Sub Two
```

How would I do this automatically in Libreoffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LibreOffice *Writer*, select in the main menu *Format*, *Bullets and Numbering...* and in the *Bullets and Numbering* dialog, select the *Outline* tab. Pick the outline style you prefer.

[image: Bullets and Numbering]

[image: Outline numbering]

[See LibreOffice *Help*](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Outline_Numbering) for more information.